# Showing that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}(2\cos\theta)^{2n}d\theta=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

As the title suggests, I would like to show that: $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}(2\cos\theta)^{2n}d\theta=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$$ for every positive integer $n$.

How can I go about doing that? I understand the that there are already solutions for the problem: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}(\cos\theta)^{2n}d\theta= {2n \choose n} \frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}$. Is there any modifications I can do to obtain the desired solution?

Comment: Trivial by $2\cos\theta=e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}$ and $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{in\theta} e^{-mi\theta}\,d\theta=2\pi \delta(m,n)$$ plus the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer for $\int_0^{2\pi} (\cos \theta)^{2n}d\theta$ is false (it is one of [Wallis' integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals)).

$$
W_{2p}=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\cos \theta)^{2p}d\theta =\frac\pi2\prod_{k=1}^p\frac{2k-1}{2k}=\frac\pi2\frac{(2p)!}{(2^pp!)^2}
$$

Changing the boundaries is easily feasible considering the periodicity and parity of $x\mapsto cos^{2n}(x)$. Thus:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} (\cos \theta)^{2n}d\theta = \frac{2}{\pi}W_{2n}$$

Then answering your question is quite straightforward:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_{0}(2\cos\theta)^{2n}d\theta=\frac{2^{2n+1}}{\pi}W_{2n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}
$$

Comment: Hi Bill, sorry for the typo to the problem. I have corrected the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Integrating by parts

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}\theta d\theta&=\Big[\cos^{2n-1}\theta\sin\theta\Big]_0^{2\pi}-\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta(2n-1)\cos^{2n-2}\theta(-\sin\theta) d\theta\\
&=(2n-1)\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^{2n-2}\theta-\cos^{2n}\theta)d\theta\\
&=(2n-1)\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^{2n-2}\theta-\cos^{2n}\theta)d\theta\\
\end{align*}

So, we have

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}\theta d\theta&=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2(n-1)}\theta d\theta\\
&=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\cdot\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2(n-2)}\theta d\theta\\
&=\dots\\
&=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\cdot\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\cdot\frac{2n-5}{2n-4}\cdots\frac{1}{2}\cdot\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\\
&=\left(\frac{2n-1}{2n}\cdot\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\cdot\frac{2n-5}{2n-4}\cdots\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{2n}{2n}\cdot\frac{2n-2}{2n-2}\cdot\frac{2n-4}{2n-4}\cdots\frac{2}{2}\right)\left(2\pi\right)\\
&=\;\frac{2\pi(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the integral by induction. First of all, you may notice that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^2 d\theta&=\frac{1}{\pi}\Big[\theta+\cos\theta\sin\theta\Big]_0^{2\pi}=2=\frac{2!}{1!1!}
\end{align*}

Thus the case $n=1$ holds. Now, integrating by parts:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n} d\theta&=\frac{2^{2n}}{2\pi}\Big(\Big[\cos^{2n-1}\theta\sin\theta\Big]_0^{2\pi}+(2n-1)\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2\theta\cos^{2n-2}\theta d\theta\Big)\\
&=\frac{2^{2n}(2n-1)}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos^{2n-2}\theta-\cos^{2n}\theta)d\theta\\
\end{align*}

then

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n} d\theta+\frac{(2n-1)}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n}d\theta&=\\ \frac{2n}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n}d\theta&=\\
&=\frac{2^{2n}(2n-1)}{2\pi\cdot2^{2n-2}}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n-2}d\theta\\
\end{align*}

that is

\begin{align*} \int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n} d\theta &=\frac{2\pi}{2n}\cdot\frac{2^{2n}(2n-1)}{2\pi\cdot2^{2n-2}}\int_0^{2\pi}(2\cos\theta)^{2n-2} d\theta=\\
&=\frac{2^2(2n-1)}{2n}\cdot\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!(n-1)!}=\frac{2n(2n-1)!}{n!n!}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi @Legoman, thanks for the detailed solution! It is very helpful for me when I consider alternative approaches to solve this problem.

Comment: You are welcome! :)